# window close confirm behavior

Tags: window, onbeforeunload

I am using `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return 'Ask question?'; };`

to prevent accidentally window close without saving data.

Also the same page the form have a submit button (save button.)

I cannot figure it out how to avoid confirmation when submit button is press.
Or maybe some kind of auto confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to redefine the `onsubmit` event of your form by removing the `onbeforeunload` event **before** te `sumbit` itself:

```
document.getElementById("yourFormId").onsubmit = function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    this.submit();
}
```

Comment: @Vasia: please consider using jquery to handle dom events... this will help you a lot when complexity will scale up :)